# How to prevent file fragmenting when you are creating archive

Tags: windows, archive, fragmentation

i have a test environment with subversion, im making DUMP files (20GB) and then compressing it. It gives me 12GB file, but with over 500 fragments.
Question is, is there a way to archive file into one file-piece? 7-zip, winrar or anything?

Thanks

Comment: How are you compressing it now?

Comment: testing winrar:
rar m -rr -t "c:\Backup\svnroot_%date%.rar" "c:\Backup\*.dump"

Comment: Ah, OK, this is a MS Windows question.  I have re-tagged it, but knowing nothing about MS Windows, I can't help; sorry.  If you try this under Linux, `gzip`/`bzip2` will compress a file *in situ* without splitting it up.

Comment: So no way for Windows? :)

Comment: Alex, this question might get better response on superuser.com.  If you'd like it transferred there, flag a moderator (via the "flag" link) and ask for it to be transferred.

Answer (score 0):

I know its not a direct answer but the fact is that the correct answer is:

500 fragments for a 12gb file is absolutely irrelevant. It would be cruel to allow Alex to continue on this rather obscure project

Comment: We're talking file fragmentation right?